# SQL into LINQ... need a nudge in the right direction

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, translate

I want to use LINQ as a DataGrivdView Datasource...  I have the correct SQL query, but I'm having a heck of a time re-writing it in LINQ...

SQL:

```
SELECT ICITEM.ITEMNO, ICITEM.[DESC], MAX(PORCPL.DTARRIVAL) AS Expr1
FROM   ICITEM INNER JOIN
        PORCPL ON PORCPL.ITEMNO = ICITEM.ITEMNO
WHERE  (ICITEM.ITEMNO LIKE '%R001%')
GROUP BY ICITEM.ITEMNO, ICITEM.[DESC]
```

My feeble attempt(s) at LINQ:

```
    Dim s = From items In db.ICITEMs
    Where items.ITEMNO.Contains(Me.txtQuery.Text) Or items.DESC.Contains(Me.txtQuery.Text)
    Join recDates In db.PORCPLs On items.ITEMNO Equals recDates.ITEMNO
    Select [Item_ID] = items.ITEMNO, [Description] = items.DESC, [rd] = recDates.DTARRIVAL
```

My LINQ Log...

```
SELECT [t0].[ITEMNO] AS [Item_ID], [t0].[DESC] AS [Description], [t1].[DTARRIVAL] AS [rd]
FROM [dbo].[ICITEM] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[PORCPL] AS [t1] ON [t0].[ITEMNO] = [t1].[ITEMNO]
WHERE ([t0].[ITEMNO] LIKE @p0) OR ([t0].[DESC] LIKE @p1)
-- @p0: Input VarChar (Size = 8000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [%r001%]
-- @p1: Input VarChar (Size = 8000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [%r001%]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1
```

I can't figure out how to get a Max function on the [rd] field... ANY insight would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `Group By`.
Here is an example which should help:

```
Dim s = From items In db.ICITEMs
Where items.ITEMNO.Contains(Me.txtQuery.Text) Or items.DESC.Contains(Me.txtQuery.Text)
Join recDates In db.PORCPLs On items.ITEMNO Equals recDates.ITEMNO
Group By items.ITEMNO, items.DESC Into MaxArrivalDate = Max(recDates.DTARRIVAL)
Select [Item_ID] = items.ITEMNO, [Description] = items.DESC, [rd] = MaxArrivalDate
```

Comment: oh thanks you so much... too many hours, I'd lost on this.  this works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You have an additional `Contains` in your linq query. If this is correct, here is the full linq query with group by and max:

```
Dim s = From items In db.ICITEMs
Where items.ITEMNO.Contains(Me.txtQuery.Text) Or items.DESC.Contains(Me.txtQuery.Text)
Join recDates In db.PORCPLs On items.ITEMNO Equals recDates.ITEMNO
Group By items.ITEMNO, items.DESC Into Group
Let MaxArrival = Group.Max(Function(p) p.recDates.DTARRIVAL)
Select [Item_ID] = ITEMNO, [Description] = DESC, [rd] = MaxArrival
```